# HTTP error with spotdl package while trying to download a playlist

Tags: python, spotify

I was using the pip package spotdl (https://pypi.org/project/spotdl/) and encountered with the following error. This occurred while trying to download a playlist.

```
ERROR: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotdl\downloader.py", line 213, in _download_list
        track_dl.download_single()
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotdl\downloader.py", line 120, in download_single
        return self._download_single(songname)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotdl\downloader.py", line 128, in _download_single
        if youtube_tools.download_song(input_song, self.content):
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\spotdl\youtube_tools.py", line 191, in download_song
        link.download(filepath=filepath)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py", line 181, in download
        downloader.download(filepath, infodict)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\common.py", line 366, in download
        return self.real_download(filename, info_dict)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\http.py", line 341, in real_download
        establish_connection()
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\downloader\http.py", line 109, in establish_connection
        ctx.data = self.ydl.urlopen(request)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pafy\backend_youtube_dl.py", line 191, in urlopen
        return g.opener.open(url)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "c:\users\anish\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
WARNING: Failed to download song. Will retry after other songs
```

Can you help me in fixing it? 
Should I change the API keys for youtube and Spotify provided in the code? Same error occurs when I try a single song.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command `youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir`. It worked for me. I also used my own Youtube API key so I'm not sure if it was both the changes or just the cache clearing that did the trick.

Comment: youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir

worked. Thank you. I'll also change the YT API. That'd be for the better I think.

Answer (score 0):

[Go through this github repo](https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader), you will understand everything though working with spotdl sometimes sucks but its one time investment once the configuration is done in your machine you are good to go for any playlist or song make sure you install ffmpeg first [ffmpeg installation guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjtmgCb8NcE).